# How to check in table have only data value using code igniter PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

i have team member table and team table. In team member table have , three columns are there teamid, staff_id and stafftype(leader or technician). Only one leader (staff_type column value) will comes in one team. So when i insert data to team member table i need to check whether any leader is there in same team.

How to show an error message that "already have leader in this team"?Team member table looks like,

```
team_id   staff_id   stafftype
1          2        leader //see here already have leader for team_id 1
2          1        other
3          8        other
1          5        Technician
2          3        Other
1          4        Leader //This should not come. becoz already teamid-1 have Leader
```

When trying to save from frond end, need to show error message ie;"already have leader in this team"

**MODAL**

```
public function addteam_memb($datas) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('team_members');
    $querySS = $this->db->get()->result();

    if(array_search('1', array_column($querySS, 'team_id')) !== false) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        $insert_id = 0;
        if ( ! empty($datas)) {
            $this->db->insert('team_members', $datas);
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function editteammember() {
    $getaddstafftype = $this->input->post( 'getaddstafftype' );
    $getaddstaffname = $this->input->post( 'getaddstaffname' );
    $getteamid = $this->input->post('getteamid');
    $getstatus = $this->input->post('getstatus');

    //if ( ! empty($getaddstaffname) ) 
    if ( ! empty($getaddstaffname) && ! empty($getaddstafftype) ) {
        foreach ($getaddstaffname as $key => $value ){
            $data['Staff_id'] = $value;
            $data['Staff_type'] = $getaddstafftype[$key];
            $data['team_id'] = $getteamid[$key];
            $data['status'] = "active";
            $value = $this->mastertable_model->addteam_memb($data); 
        }

        if($value == 1) {
            echo "Already have leader in this team";
        } else {
            //$this->load->view('team_memb_creation');        
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: do a select query before the insert to check for a "leader"

Comment: Which database system are you using mysql or sql-server?

Comment: First check if $data['Staff_type']  is a leader, if not insert the data else check if the team has a leader , you only have to add a where Clause to your Select for teamid and status leader , if the result  is empty insert $data else give back 1 . It is strait forward

Comment: @nbk is it possible to edit my code?plz

Comment: @nbk i need to check active status column also. While checking any Leader in the staff_type column where only the status active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with the existing array_search, but I'm guessing that it's an initial attempt at getting the leader check working? If that's not the case let me know

You're on the right general track, querying the table first to check for conflicts, just not quite the right execution.

What you need to do is

- If you're adding a leader check if that team already has a leader
- If so, handle it somehow
- Otherwise continue with the insert

Try something like the below. The input should be an array with keys corresponding to database columns. EG:

```
$datas = [
    'team_id' => 1,
    'staff_id' => 3,
    'stafftype' => 'leader'
]
```

```
// Its a good idea to use constants for things like this
const STAFFTYPE_LEADER = 'leader';


/**
 * Add a team member to the database 
 *
 * Input array must be an array representing a team member to be added,
 * with key names that match database column names.
 *
 * @param array $datas 
 * @throws Exception If adding a leader when one already exists
 */
public function addteam_memb($datas) {
    // Lower case conversion just for consistency. 
    $staffType = strtolower($datas['Staff_type']);

    // Only run the query if we're trying to add a team lead
    // Otherwise there's no need to worry
    if ($staffType === self::STAFFTYPE_LEADER) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('team_members');
        $this->db->where('team_id', $datas['team_id'])
        $this->db->where('stafftype', self::STAFFTYPE_LEADER)

        if ($this->db->count_all_results() >= 1) {
            // Team leader already exists, handle however you would like
            // I would typically recommend an exception, but thats up to you!
            throw new Exception('Team leader exists');
        }

        // Reset query before moving on to the insert
        $this->db->reset_query();
    }

    // Either we're not adding a leader, or there is no current leader
    // so go ahead with the insert
    $insert_id = 0;
    if ( ! empty($datas)) {
        $this->db->insert('team_members', $datas);
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }

}
```

It's worth noting that your code so far seems to have a bit of a mismatch between `editing` and `adding` that hasn't been addressed here. This function assumes you're only adding new members, not editing existing ones. you'll need something more for that case.

Comment: Message: Illegal string offset 'Staff_type' warning is coming at the line of $staffType = strtolower($datas['Staff_type']);

Comment: Error Number: 42S22

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name '1'.

INSERT INTO team_members (1) VALUES ('')

Comment: The first of those means you're passing in a string instead of an array, The second means you're probably passing an empty array. You need to pass in an associative array with keys that match the DB columns

Comment: can u plz edit my controller function code???How i need to pass the data?

Comment: when i try to print $datas result is Array ( [Staff_id] => 3 [Staff_type] => Leader [team_id] => 1 [status] => active )

Comment: foreach($datas as $k => $v)
   {
    print $k . " => " . $v . " <br />";
   }

Comment: its print like Staff_id => 1 
Staff_type => Leader 
team_id => 1 
status => active

Comment: still am not getting the proper data .can u plz edit my controller function.

Comment: is it possible to edit my controller function???becoz am getting wrong data

Comment: Spamming with no useful information tends to do the exact opposite of getting people want to help you. But if those keys match the database columns then it should be ok.

I added a call to reset_query() to the example that may or may not be required (been a long time since I used codeIgniter so not too sure)

Comment: u r passing data like $datas = [
    'team_id' => 1,
    'staff_id' => 3,
    'stafftype' => 'leader'
]

Comment: when i try to print $datas result is Array ( [Staff_id] => 3 [Staff_type] => Leader [team_id] => 1 [status] => active ) HOW TO CONVERT IT LIKE URS?